# Database table not deleted if it's empty

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have an issue with the following code as it seems:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "project_name_" . $result2->projectname;
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");
```

It delets the table if it has content in it. Greate! But in some cases the table may be completely empty. In the case where it's totaly empty the databse table is not deleted. Why?

How to fix this?

Kind regards
Johan

Comment: Given that this is explicitly NOT the expected outcome of the SQL statement, you should probably start by looking for errors - this *should* be implemented in your code, but should should also be visible in the MySQL general log (if the command got to the DBMS)

Answer (score 0):

Test the return of that function.

**query (string)**: The SQL query you wish to execute.

This function returns an integer value indicating the number of rows affected/selected. For `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `TRUNCATE` and `DROP` SQL statements, this function returns `TRUE` on success. If a MySQL error is encountered, the function will return `FALSE`. Note that since both `0` and `FALSE` may be returned, you can use the equality `==` operator to test for falsy returns (i.e., a returned value that is logically `FALSE`). Using the identicality `===` operator may result in unexpected behavior as it compares the types returned in addition to the values...

[Class Reference/wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)